# category filter with ajax and symfony

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, filter, twig

On a website made with symfony, I would like the user being able to display questions of a category by clicking on a button.

For now, clicking on a category returns the all page. And, I don't have any errors in my console.

Here's the code :

**app.js**

```
function helpFilterAction() {
    $(".helpCategoryFilter").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var category = $(this).text().trim();
        $.ajax({
            url: $this.attr('action'),
            type: $this.attr('method'),
            data: 'category='+category,
            success: function(data) {
                if (!$.trim(data)){
                    $('#faq_list').html("<p class='content__text'>Nothing</p>");
                }
                else{
                    $('#faq_list').html(data);
                    $(".loading").hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**FaqController.php**

```
/**
* Search for faq entities with categories
*
* @Route("/category", name="faq_category")
* @Method({"POST"})
*/
public function helpFilterAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $category = '';
        $category = $request->get('category');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        if ($category != '') {
            $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
            $qb->add('select', 'a');
            $qb->leftJoin('a.category', 'c');
            $qb->where('c.name LIKE :category');
            $qb->setParameter('category', $category);

            $query = $qb->getQuery();
            $faqs = $query->getResult();
        } else {
            $faqs = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Faq')->findAll();
        }

        return $this->render(
            'faq/list.html.twig',
            array(
                'faqs' => $faqs,
            )
        );
    } else {
        return $this->indexAction();
    }
}
```

**Faq.php**

```
/**
 * Faq
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="faq")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FaqRepository")
 */
class Faq
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="question", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="answer", type="text")
     */
    private $answer;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FaqCategory", inversedBy="faqs")
     */
    private $category;

    ...
}
```

**FaqCategory.php**

```
/**
 * FaqCategory
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="faq_category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FaqCategoryRepository")
 */
class FaqCategory
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Faq", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $faqs;

    ...
}
```

**index.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="linearBg site-pusher help--pusher">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content__title">
                <h2 class="content__titleText">Aide</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="content__text mobile-not-displayed">
                <p class="content__textText">Vous retrouverez-ici les nombreux conseils et informations concernant les différents services qu’offrent notre plateforme</p>
            </div>

            <form id="faq_search" action="{{ path('faq_search') }}" method="post" class="searchForm--help">
                <input id="appbundle_research_faq_keyword" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Comment réserver mon billet ?" class="searchForm__input--help">
                <button type="submit" class="searchForm__submit--help">CHERCHER</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="helpCategoriesFilter" class="helpCategoriesFilter">
            {% for faqcategory in faqcategorys %}
                <div class="helpCategoryFilterContent">
                    <div class="helpCategoryFilter">
                        <div class="helpCategoryFilterTitle">
                            {{ faqcategory.name }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="helpCategoryFilterBg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <div class="loading"></div>
        <div id="faq_list" class="content content__help">
            {% include 'faq/list.html.twig' %}
        </div>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**list.html.twig**

```
{% for faq in faqs %}
    <div class="helpContent">
        <div id="helpCard1" class="helpContent__card">
            <div class="helpContent__title">
                {{ faq.question }}
            </div>
            <div class="helpContent__chevron">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/icons/Chevron.svg') }}" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="helpContent1" class="helpContent__text not-displayed">
            {{ faq.answer }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: can you add your twig?

Comment: @JohnnyDew yep, it's done

Comment: What do you mean by returns `all page`? What do you exactly get in response?

Comment: @Jeet I get the current HTML page

Comment: In Browser console, do you see relevant page being loaded ? Or is it loading the current page. I guess, the ajax is hitting to the same page.

Comment: @Jeet in the browser console, `data` contains the current page. So when I click on a category, the page is displayed 2 times

Comment: @Jeet just find out that `$this.attr('action')` and `$this.attr('method')` are returning `undefined`. How can I get the url for the ajax call in my app.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FaqController.php**

You have to replace `$category = $request->get('category');` by `$category = $request->request->get('category');`.
You can look at Symfony's documentation at https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object

You should also redirect to `indexAction` instead of calling it. So it should look like this `return $this->redirectToRoute('index');` instead. Where `index` is the name of your route.

Also, like you pointed out in your comment, you have to have change `$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');` to `$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('a');` and `$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a'); $qb->add('select', 'a'); $qb->leftJoin('a.category', 'c');` to `$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('a'); $qb->select('a'); $qb->from('AppBundle:Faq', 'a'); qb->leftJoin('a.category', 'c');`

**index.html.twig**

Replace the line `<div class="helpCategoryFilter">` by `<div class="helpCategoryFilter" data-href="{{ path('faq_category') }}">`

**app.js**

Should look like this instead to get the action and method from your form and not from the div that you are getting the category from.

```
function helpFilterAction() {
    $(".helpCategoryFilter").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var url = $(this).attr('data-href');
        var category = $(this).text().trim();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'category='+category,
            success: function(data) {
                if (!$.trim(data)){
                    $('#faq_list').html("<p class='content__text'>Nothing</p>");
                }
                else{
                    $('#faq_list').html(data);
                    $(".loading").hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `var form = $('#faq_search');` give the **faq_search** route but I want **faq_category** route. By setting a `data-href="{{ path('faq_category') }}"` and getting the data-href with `var $url = $(this).data('href');` I have the **faq_category** route. But I have a POST 500 (internal server error). I guess there is somthing wrong with my query but I can't find what, do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the new information your have provided.

Comment: The exact reason of error 500 is : "Attempted to call an undefined method named "createQueryBuilder" of class "AppBundle\Controller\FaqController". Did you mean to call "createFormBuilder"?"

Comment: To fix it I had to change `$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');` by `$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('a');` but I have another error 500 **No alias was set before invoking getRootAlias()."** and to fix this one I had to change `$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
            $qb->add('select', 'a');
            $qb->leftJoin('a.category', 'c');` by `$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('a');
                $qb->select('a');
                $qb->from('AppBundle:Faq', 'a');
                $qb->leftJoin('a.category', 'c');` Can you edit your answer so I can accept it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just saw you haven't added a `action` attribute in your clickable div element.

A quick answer, Here is how you should add the path to be read on jQuery `Click` Event :

```
<div id="helpCategoriesFilter" class="helpCategoriesFilter">
    {% for faqcategory in faqcategorys %}
        <div class="helpCategoryFilterContent">
            <div class="helpCategoryFilter" data-href="{{ path('ajax_path_route_name_here') }}">
                <div class="helpCategoryFilterTitle">
                    {{ faqcategory.name }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="helpCategoryFilterBg">
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And here is how you should collect the `data-href` value in your jQuery Event :

```
function helpFilterAction() {
    $(".helpCategoryFilter").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $url = $(this).data('href');
        var category = $(this).text().trim();
        $.ajax({
            url: $url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {"category" : category},
            success: function(data) {
                if (!$.trim(data)){
                    $('#faq_list').html("<p class='content__text'>Nothing</p>");
                }
                else{
                    $('#faq_list').html(data);
                    $(".loading").hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I haven't gone through in details with your code. But, I would suggest you should debug `Symfony Controller` only after you see the `Ajax` is hitting the correct url.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have the good route now, thanks. But why we use GET and not POST? And I still have an error 500. I guess there is something wrong with my query. Can you see any mistakes?